# Get Firestore Feilds Details And Display Into Dards

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i get my data from firestore and put the name and image inside ListView.builder
same like in the image [first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96ACl.jpg)

when i press on the ListTile than it Navigat me to another page Carddetails.dart

i want display every ListTile data fields inside cards same data inside the picture
[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYoQw.jpg)

Comment: Please share some code. Share the model of object you are retrieving from firebase.

Comment: @BilalSaeed can i contact you ?

Comment: Details are in the description of my profile.